# How can i maximize the performance of this C code?

Tags: c, performance

I have written a code that basically asks the user to input 2 strings which it compares to find if they are anagrams or not. Im new to C and I know the code works fine but I don't know if it works well. I know its a relatively small code so the difference in performance would be negligible but I still want to learn

Someways I have thought of minimizing memory usage was by using data types like int8_t instead of int for a number that will never reach above 127. My while loops were a bunch of if statements before so that's one way I've faster. Also used && and II instead of extra if conditions. How else could I make the code work better?

Is it better for me to use `put("...")` instead of `print("...\n")` for the long string lines since they have no other purpose than displaying only strings? Is there a way to make the size of the array 26 instead of 128 since I am only concerned about the lower case alphabet? Are there any unwritten universal laws of coding that I need to know about to make my code more efficient?

```
/*  This code takes two input strings and detects whether they are anagrams. This is
    done by defining two functions, 'is_length() and 'is_anagram()'. is_length makes 
    sure both strings are a maximum of 10 strings. is_anagram() scans each character  
    on both strings and adds 1 to the elements corresponding to the character's  
    equivalent ASCII number. This produces two arrays of 128 elements which it  
    compares to check if the two words are anagrams   
 */

// Libraries used in the code 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

void is_length(char str1[], char str2[]) {
    while (strlen(str1) > 10 || strlen(str2) > 10) {
        printf("\nMake sure the words are a maximum 10 characters\n");
        printf("Input two words:\n");
        gets(str1);
        gets(str2);
    }
}

int8_t is_anagram(char str1[], char str2[]) {   // Defining a function detects anagrams
    int8_t size1 = strlen(str1);                // Finding the sizes of the strings
    int8_t size2 = strlen(str2);

    if (size1 == size2) {                       // Checking if they are the same length
        int16_t str1Arr[128] = {};              // Defining an array with 128 elements
        int16_t str2Arr[128] = {};
        
        while (*str1) {
            str1Arr[(int16_t)*str1]++;          // Scanning each character in the    
            str1++;                             // string and adding 1 to the element  
        }                                       // corresponding their ASCII equivalent  
        while (*str2) {                          // number
            str2Arr[(int16_t)*str2]++;              
            str2++;
        }

        uint8_t i;
        for (i = 128; i--;) {                   // Comparing the string array elements
            if (str1Arr[i] != str2Arr[i]) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("The words are not the same length so... \n");
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char word1[10] = {};                        // Defining variables for the strings
    char word2[10] = {};

    printf("Input two words: \n");              // Aquiring input strings from user
    gets(word1);
    gets(word2);
    is_length(word1, word2);                     // Recalling is_length()
                                   
    if ((is_anagram(strlwr(word1), strlwr(word2))) == 1) {    // Converting to lower case 
        printf("YES! The words are anagrams \n");           // and recalling is_anagram()
    } else {                                                  // to compare the two strings
        printf("NO, The words are not anagrams \n");
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Don't use gets(), or your program might run forever...

Comment: Using smaller data types for local variables (that are allocated on the stack) is more likely than not to actually *reduce*  performance (because the compiler needs to insert casts or conversions in a lot of operations)

Comment: A omment on the algorithm, use just one array, increment it for one string, decrement it for the other string, check it's all zeros at the end. Less memory and a faster check.

Comment: What is `strlwr()`?

Comment: @wildplasser what do you mean by run forever? The code ends when the while condition ends. The reason I used gets() instead of scanf() was so that it reads the whole line. So something like "hello there" and "HTell O" is also classed as anagrams. Are there any benefits of using scanf() in this case that I don't know about?

Comment: I was wrong actually, `strlwr` appears to be a C function, not sure if it is standard though. Apologies for the mistake. EDIT It seems like they are deprecated MS functions. `_strlwr` seems to be the non-deprecated version

Comment: `gets()` dont use it. ever. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morris_worm

Comment: @Jeban `gets` an evil, maniacal, mess of a function, drafted into the standard library at a time when people naively believed computers would always be programmed  with competence, and used without malice. It is a dinosaur, and a recipe for a buffer overflow exploit by its very nature. It is so bad it has been *removed* from modern C standard libraries.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 _strlwr appears to be a C function_. Are you sure? I've never heard of that function

Comment: @DavidRanieri Blame Borland. it was their doing a very long time ago.At least that was the first time I saw it, some 30 years and a lifetime away.

Comment: @DavidRanieri In the edit, I have said that it is a function in Microsoft's C library.

Comment: @wildplasser thanks, exactly the type of stuff I was I asking about

Comment: @12345ieee Sorry if its a trivial question but it is faster since its checking each element once rather than using an extra array (less memory usage) and checking two sets of 128 elements right?

Comment: @Jeban The memory benefit is obvious. On the speed side, in the filling phase it changes very little, the start of the 2nd loop might be sliiigtly faster due to the array already being in cache, but the real advantage is in the checking, comparing against a fixed number (0) needs one less load from memory and comparing against 0 is especially efficient in almost all arches.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I maximize the performance of this C code?

- Instead of recomputing string length many times, compute once and pass around the length.
- No need to call `strlwr()` until after string length equal test.  With long strings, consider skipping `strlwr()` on original strings and instead, after all `++`, `--` on `a2i[]`, add together the letter sums.

When strings are short, sort and compare.  Research `qsort()`.

When strings are long, proceed as originally coded with some changes:

- Use a single 256 `int` array to handle all `char` values.

  ```
    // int16_t str1Arr[128] = {};
    // int16_t str2Arr[128] = {};
    int s2A[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = { 0 };

    while (*str1) {
      s2A[(unsigned char)*str1++]++;
      s2A[(unsigned char)*str2++]--;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= UCHAR_MAX; i++) {
      if (s2A[i]) { // Non-zero?
        return 0;
      }
    }
    return 1;
  ```

---

Replace `gets()`.  Research `fgets()`.

Comment: A couple ideas: 1) Doing separate filling loops may or may not be faster than a single loop, depends on the size of the string and how the caching works out 2) to check the final buffer against zero, you can reinterpret it as the widest type you have and do less comparisons (e.g. a 64bit type will save 7/8th of the iterations). It's a cute toy problem.